# MySQL - how should the table look like?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this piece of code in Java I found somewhere, but it's missing the SQL table for it.

```
 try (PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM proxyip WHERE ? LIKE CONCAT(proxyip, '%')")) {
            ps.setString(1, getSessionIPAddress());
```

how would the table look like? if it's ps.steString(1, I suppose the first column is id (integer) and the second one is the ip as varchar, but what is it called?
Thanks.

Comment: if you have access to the database, check it there. If it's just some random piece of code you found, no way to know

Answer (score 2):

SELECT COUNT(*) will return one singular integer but you cannot see the structure of the table from this query. You need to run:

```
DESC proxyip;
```

This will give you the structure.

Answer (score 0):

Impossible to know, since * means all columns and the only name I see in your code is the tablename.